# Localized App Icons with Retina Display for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, icons, localized

I have issues showing a localized app icon with retina display support.

How could this be done?

I tried to make Icon.png and Icon@2x.png localized, then I tried to make the proj-Info.plist localized and try to link to different Images.

But only the Icon of the project language are being shown...

Answer (score 5):

You need to create one infoplist.strings file for each of the language. For that, create language.lproj folders manually and put Infoplist.string file in each of the folder. 
Inside the file enter the following: CFBundleIconFile="Icon_en.png" or CFBundleIconFile = "Icon_pt.png".

Comment: Hi Edmar, thanks for your quick answer! Do I need to delete the Icon setting from the normal plist file from the project? Thanks Tom

Comment: No, you just need to add one more plist file. The other way is to duplicate your target (so you will have to plists, one for each target) and set CFBundleIconFiles for each target you have.

Comment: Hi Edmar, sorry I don't get it to work :/ The display name works fine, but not the icon
File En:
`CFBundleIconFile="Icon_en.png";
CFBundleName="Bundle Eng1";
CFBundleDisplayName="Bundle Eng2";`

File De
`CFBundleIconFile="Icon_de.png";
CFBundleName="Bundle Deu1";
CFBundleDisplayName="Bundle Deu2";`

Am I doing sth wrong?

Thanks Tom

Comment: Hi Edmar,
thanks for your test project! I got now how you meant it. 
But there is no way to create a single app which I can submit to apple with a localized App Icon?! So I need to create several apps, right?
Thanks
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom. I don't think you can change App Icon in runtime. One step you have to take when submitting to the app store is also submiting an icon (512x512px) for Artwork (showed in iTunes and App Store description). So It would be weird if the app shows an icon different from app store or even your iTunes.