# How to localize an app icon?

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I am comfortable with localizing strings and images within the app. But I am having a lot of difficulty trying to localize the app icon for my supported languages (english and german).

Is this even possible? According to the Apple documentation, you can:

> An iOS application should be internationalized and have a
>   language.lproj folder for each language it supports. In addition to
>   providing localized versions of your application’s custom resources,
>   **you can also localize your application icons and launch images by
>   placing files with the same name in your language-specific project
>   directories**. Even if you provide localized versions, however, you
>   should always include a default version of these files at the
>   top-level of your application bundle. The default version is used in
>   situations where a specific localization is not available. For more
>   information about localized resources, see “Localized Resources in
>   Bundles.”

I have tried to do this with no luck. There doesn't seem to be any helpful resources?

Other things I've tried:

[Localized App Icons with Retina Display for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762751/localized-app-icons-with-retina-display-for-ios)

https://iphonedevsdk.vanillaforums.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/77660-i-have-problem-localizing-application-icon.html

Has anyone successfully achieved a localized app icon?

Comment: How did you test this? This has always been working flawlessly for me.

Comment: Did you completely delete you app from the device when doing this? Adding localization will sometimes not work when just updating the app from Xcode.

Comment: i thought it was as simple as tossing the icon in your folder, if your having trouble delete the app and try a new clean and build

Comment: I am testing on the simulator. I have reset content and settings and also cleaned the build to ensure I start a fresh.

Comment: I know it is not a real solution but have you tried [that](http://www.badrit.com/blog/2011/6/14/localization-of-your-ios-application-s-icon-png) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since iOS 4.0, this simply doesn't seem to be possible anymore. As of 2015, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW16) has been updated and now only states that Launch Images can be localized (but does not mention App Icons anymore).

The fact that this isn't working has been confirmed by an an Apple employee on the devforums (login required) in 2010:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/330960

Bugreports have been submitted for several years, but nothing has changed. I suppose Apple wants you to use the same icon for your app all over the world – or create separate apps for specific markets.

Comment: Is this still the case in May 2014? Thanks.

Comment: @brainray Yes. Here's hoping that Apple will introduce Xcode 6 with support for localized `.xcassets` at WWDC next week... :)

Comment: as far as i know it isnt possible to localize `.xcassets` until now

Comment: @donmarkusi Unfortunately, you're absolutely correct. This still is not possible and maybe never will be.

Comment: A year later still not yet supported? or is it somewhere hidden in Xcode 7?

Comment: @ddnl It's still not possible, and probably never will be.

Comment: Is this still the case in July 2020?

Comment: @nuyanait Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Any updates in March 2023?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a way to localize the AppIcon. By using the alternative App Icon. You can change the app icon at the run time.

```
        if Locale.current.language.languageCode?.identifier == "en" {
            UIApplication.shared.setAlternateIconName("AppIcon-en") { (error) in
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Here is some [additional detail](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-change-your-app-icon-dynamically-with-setalternateiconname) on how to set up the possible icons. Also note that this solution doesn't let you change the icon in the store before you download the app.